# find controls in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#

private TableLayoutPanel CreateLayoutpan()
                    {
                        pTablePanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
                        pTablePanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
                        pTablePanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute,30));
                        pTablePanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
                        pTablePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(165, 223);
                        pTablePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 14);
                        pTablePanel.TabIndex = 0;
                        pTablePanel.Controls.Clear();
                        pTablePanel.ColumnCount =2;
                        return pTablePanel;
                    }

```
PictureBox pict;
            private void AddtoPbx(Image im)
            {
                try
                {
                    pict = new PictureBox();
                    pict.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                    pict.Padding = new Padding(2);

                     pict.Image = m;                                                              pict.Width = 100;
                    pict.Height = 60;

                    pict.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                    CheckBox chkBx = new CheckBox();
                    chkBx.Name = "checkImage";
                    chkBx.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 40);

                    pTablePanel.Controls.Add(chkBx, 0, iCount);
                    pTablePanel.Controls.Add(pict, 1, iCount);
                    iCount++;                       
                    pTablePanel.AutoScroll = true;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                    pict.Focus();
                    STA_gbxImages.Controls.Add(pTablePanel);


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {     }
            }
```

here i ll add chkbox as well as image in a row....
now my problem is if the chkbox is checked i need to add ccorresponding image in other collection .... how to do this please help me...

Answer (score 0):

When creating dynamic controls, don't add them to the form directly. Just put a PlaceHolder control and add your  table to it.
Then, use FinfControl() from your Placeholder: `PlaceHodler1.FindControl("table1")`